# msbuild copy files

Tags: file, msbuild, copy, tfsbuild

I am having trouble copying files with MSbuild and the error messages I'm getting seem to contradict each other (using TFS 2008 to do the build).

I currently having the following in my build script

```
 <PropertyGroup>
      <ReleaseRoot>$(DropLocation)\Latest\x86\Release</ReleaseRoot>
      <WebRoot>$(ReleaseRoot)\_PublishedWebsites\Web</WebRoot>
      <DBRoot>$(ReleaseRoot)\Database</DBRoot>
      <TempHolingDir>$(ReleaseRoot)\temp)</TempHolingDir>
      <WebConfig>$(WebRoot)\Web.config</WebConfig>
      <DatabaseUpdate>$(DBRoot)\databaseupdate.exe</DatabaseUpdate>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Copy SourceFiles="$(WebConfig);$(DatabaseUpdate)" DestinationFolder="$(TempHoldingDir)" ContinueOnError="false" />
```

When I run the build I get

> error MSB3023: No destination
>   specified for Copy. Please supply
>   either "DestinationFiles" or
>   "DestinationDirectory".

I then change the DestinationFolder to DestinationDirectory and I got

> error MSB4064: The
>   "DestinationDirectory" parameter is
>   not supported by the "Copy" task.
>   Verify the parameter exists on the
>   task, and it is a settable public
>   instance property. error MSB4063: The
>   "Copy" task could not be initialized
>   with its input parameters.

THese errors seem to contradict each other, what exactly am I missing here?

Comment: seems DestinationDirectory indeed doesn't exist but still not sure why the task is failinging...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62d6c530%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's DestinationFolder according to [Copy Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), looks like MSB3023 error text is wrong?

Answer (score 11):

Restarting Visual Studio resolved this for me, so adding this as a potential solution for anyone else experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you called your property TempHolingDir when your referred to it as TempHoldingDir.
Its all about the d.

Comment: update your question pls then. Also the value is wrong too: $(ReleaseRoot)\temp)