# Copy file using MSBUILD

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I am working on a white label xamarin application, and I would like to copy a file from the executing project to the shared .net standard project.

Example

If ClientA.Android project is currently running, I would like to copy a specific file from that project to the .Net Standard project based on if its debug or release config.

I know to copy from a different folder in the same project.

```
<Target Name="CopyConfigFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
<Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/Configuration-Source/$(Configuration)/config.json" DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/Configuration/" />
</Target>
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me to copy from the executing project rather.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [msbuild copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528459/msbuild-copy-files)